# I don't know what I'm misssing(Turtle)

Tags: python

I'm using *Trinket* to run my *python*.

I have been tinkering with it for days and it keeps giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/tmp/sessions/5ecd67058b43cfc0/main.py", line 2, in
    setup(500, 500)   File "", line 6, in setup   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 3662, in Screen
    Turtle._screen = _Screen()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 3678, in __init__
    _Screen._root = self._root = _Root()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 434, in __init__
    TK.Tk.__init__(self)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1871, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Here is the code so far:

```
from turtle import *
setup(500, 500)
Screen()
title("Turtle Keys")
move = Turtle()
showturtle()
def k1():
 move.forward(100)
 move.left(90)
 move.forward(100)
 move.left(90)
 move.forward(100)
 move.left(90)
 move.forward(100)
 move.left(90)
def k2():
 move.forward(320)
 move.left(120)
 move.forward(320)
 move.left(120)
 move.forward(320)
 move.left(120)
 
def k3():
    move.right(45)
def k4():
 move.forward(100)
 move.left(90)
 move.forward(50)
 move.left(90)
 move.forward(100)
 move.left(90)
 move.forward(50)
 move.left(90)
 
def k5():
 move.left(10)
 
def k6():
 move.forward(10)
 
def k7():
 move.backward(10)
 
onkey(k1, "Up")
onkey(k2, "Left")
onkey(k3, "Right")
onkey(k4, "Down")
onkey(k5, "1")
onkey(k6, "2")
onkey(k7, "3")
listen()
mainloop()
```

The objective is to draw certain shapes when certain keys are pressed.

Comment: In the future you should also check out what makes a [mcve] - you could use a *much* smaller code sample to exhibit the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about https://trinket.io/python, it looks like you haven't [read the docs](https://trinket.io/docs/python) too closely - there's a limited subset of Turtle that Trinket actually supports, and none of it involves user interaction.

If you want to have keyboard interaction and Turtle, you're going to need to [install Python on your own machine](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Comment: @EdRandall Apparently I should have added the content here, as it appears not to have been indexed by the Internet Archive. Also, I guess it appears they support even *less* Tkinter now ;)

Answer (score 0):

repl.it at least supports graphics and tells you the errors in your program instead of the unhelpful $DISPLAY variable error - Try https://repl.it/languages/python_turtle.

But it still doesn't seem to support keyboard input that you are trying to use.  If you comment out setup() and title() and also remove the onkey() / listen() code,  replacing instead with some hard calls to your functions, you can at least get some output.

Install Python locally - https://www.python.org/downloads/ - to get a full-featured environment.